# How to check status of android phone screen is locked or unlocked using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i want to know how to get the status of android phone screen whether its locked or unlocked using monkeyrunner . please help .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** (>= 4.7.0) (which uses python instead of monkeyrunner`) you can do

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
if device.isLocked():
    device.wake()
    device.unlock()
```